# Laplace transform of $f(t)=te^{-t}\sin(2t)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, laplace-transform, signal-processing

I was asked to find the Laplace transform of the function $\displaystyle f(t)=te^{-t}\sin(2t)$ using only the properties of Laplace transform, meaning, use clever tricks and the table shown at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms

So it's not actually needed to calculate $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty te^{-st-t}\sin (2t)\:dt$

but rather, find **shortcuts** and ways to make it easier **using the table** and **properties** of the Laplace transform.

I'm really stuck. I can't find anything to make it easier. Calculating the integral seems inevitable. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Use Frequency shifting and Frequency domain differentiation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an approach.

1. $\displaystyle \mathcal{L}(\sin 2t) = \frac{2}{s^2 + 2^2} =
       \frac{2}{s^2 + 4}$, using the table.
2. $\displaystyle \mathcal{L} (e^{-t} \sin 2t) = \frac{2}{(s + 1)^2 +
       4}$, using frequency shifting.
3. $\displaystyle \mathcal{L}( t  e^{-t} \sin 2t) =
       -\frac{d}{ds}\!\left(\frac{2}{(s + 1)^2 + 4}\right) =  \frac{4 (s+1)}{\left((s+1)^2+4\right)^2}$, using frequency differentiation.

Comment: That looks really cool! Do you know of a book/site/pdf that I can learn about frequency shifting/differentiation from, @OliverOloa?

Comment: @KhallilBenyattou Thanks. This book seems interesting for the standard properties of the Laplace transform:http://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/4243/Laplace.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t)=te^{−t}\sin(2t)=tg(t)$ and $g(t)=e^{−t}\sin(2t)=e^{−t}h(t)$ with $h(t)=\sin(2t)$. So $F(s)=-G'(s)$ and $G(s)=H(s+1)$ with $H(s)=\frac{2}{s^2+4}$.